# Rspec model tests failing due to custom validation method not being found

Tags: ruby, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

For some reason my Rspec Model tests are failing for one of my models due to a custom validation method that is being called, but not found within the test. At least that's what I think is happening. This validation is triggered when the form is submitted to create a new Dinosaur in the app. Can anyone tell me why this may be happening and what a potential fix may be?

This is the failure error for all 4 tests:

```
Failure/Error: if cage.at_capacity?
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `at_capacity?' for nil:NilClass
```

Model/dinosaur.rb

```
class Dinosaur < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :cage
    validates :name, :species, :diet_type, :cage_id, presence: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
    validate :is_cage_at_capacity
    validate :is_cage_powered_down
    validate :cage_contains_diet_mismatch

=begin
    def set_cage(c)

        return false if c.at_capacity?
        cage = c

    end

    def move_dino_to_powered_down_cage(c)

        return false if c.is_powered_down?
        cage = c

    end
=end

    def is_herbivore?
        return diet_type == "Herbivore"
    end

    def is_carnivore?
        return diet_type == "Carnivore"
    end

    def is_cage_powered_down
        if cage.is_powered_down?
            errors.add(:cage_id, "Chosen cage is powered down. Please choose another cage!")
        end
    end

    def is_cage_at_capacity
        if cage.at_capacity?
            errors.add(:cage_id, "Chosen cage is full. Please choose another cage!")
            end
    end

    def cage_contains_diet_mismatch
        if cage.has_carnivore == true and is_herbivore?
            errors.add(:cage_id, "Chosen cage contains carnivores! This dinosaur will be eaten!")
        else
            if cage.has_herbivore == true and is_carnivore?
                errors.add(:cage_id, "Chosen cage contains herbivores! This dinosaur will eat the others!")
            end
        end
    end


end
```

spec/models/dinosaur_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Dinosaur, type: :model do

    it "is valid with valid attributes" do
        dinosaur = Dinosaur.new(name:"Yellow", species:"Tyrranosaurus", diet_type:"Carnivore", cage_id: 7)
        expect(dinosaur).to be_valid
    end

    it "is not valid without a name" do
        dinosaur = Dinosaur.new(name: nil)
        expect(dinosaur).to_not be_valid
    end
    it "is not valid without a max capacity" do
        dinosaur = Dinosaur.new(species: nil)
        expect(dinosaur).to_not be_valid
    end
    it "is not valid without a power status" do
        dinosaur = Dinosaur.new(diet_type: nil)
        expect(dinosaur).to_not be_valid
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

**Why this happening?**

When you call method `valid?` all validations are triggered. At least, `is_cage_at_capacity` calls `dinosaur.cage.at_capacity?`. However, `Dinosaur.new(diet_type: nil)` does not have any cage so the exception is raised.

**How can you fix it?**

The simplest way would be to add a cage in your tests:

```
cage = Cage.new
dinosaur = cage.build_dinosaur(params)
```

It could be quite repetetive to build all these objects every time, so consider using [FactoryBot with associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations).

When testing validations it is more precise to test an expected error instead of the whole object state. Check [this](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/af87b1eaa8-test-validation-errors-with-rspec).

For built-in validations (e.g. presence, uniqueness) better use [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when the execution of the program reaches the `is_cage_at_capacity` method the cage is not set, actually the error has a clue: `undefined method 'at_capacity?' for nil:NilClass` this means that you are trying to send the method `at_capacity?` to a nil object.

So, I think some options to fix it will be to make sure a cage is associated with the Dinosaur when created or to add a guard clause to the `is_cage_at_capacity` method, something like this:

```
def is_cage_at_capacity
  if cage.nil?
    errors.add(:cage_id, "There is not a cage associated with the dinosaur")
  end

  if cage.at_capacity?
    errors.add(:cage_id, "Chosen cage is full. Please choose another cage!")
  end
end
```